# Script in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: java, freemarker, libreoffice

With LibreOffice Writer, I can enter scripts into the document (insert->script). These show up as `<text:script script:language ="...">...</text:script>` in the `content.xml` of the `.odt`-file. When using the jodreports jar file, I can get these scripts to work as described in http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/?q=node/25.

Now I want to do the same for the other LibreOffice document types, but there is no option to insert->script in Calc or Impress. The only thing I see is macro's, but they are stored in separate xml files, not `content.xml`. I'm sure jodreports will do the job if only I can get the right tag in the `content.xml` file to enter my script...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a change in the jodreports code. This will not add the requested `<text:script>` tag in the `.odt` file, so it may strictly speaking not be an answer to the specifically asked question, but it will solve the underlying problem of getting jodreports to play nice with LibreOffice Calc files.

The change - using [jodreports 2.4.0](http://sourceforge.net/p/jodreports/code/HEAD/tree/) code - is in the `net.sf.jooreports.templates.xmlfilters`-package, in the file `ScriptTagFilter.java`. In the function `doFilter`, I've replaced

```
Nodes scriptNodes = document.query("//text:script[translate(@script:language, 'CIJOPRST', 'cijoprst')='jooscript']", XPATH_CONTEXT);
```

with

```
    //WRITER document (odt)
    Nodes odtScriptNodes = document.query("//text:script[translate(@script:language, 'CIJOPRST', 'cijoprst')='jooscript']", XPATH_CONTEXT);
    Nodes scriptNodes = odtScriptNodes;

    //CALC document (ods)
    Nodes odsPotentialScriptNodes = document.query("//table:table-cell", XPATH_CONTEXT);
    for(int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < odsPotentialScriptNodes.size(); nodeIndex++){
        Element tableCellElement = (Element) odsPotentialScriptNodes.get(nodeIndex);
        Elements textElements = tableCellElement.getChildElements();
        if(textElements.size() > 0 && textElements.get(0).getValue().toLowerCase().startsWith("--!jooscript:")){
            String fullScript = textElements.get(0).getValue().substring("--!jooscript:".length());
            for(int elementIndex = 1; elementIndex < textElements.size(); elementIndex++){
                fullScript += System.getProperty("line.separator") + textElements.get(elementIndex).getValue();
            }
            for(int elementIndex = textElements.size()-1; elementIndex > 0; elementIndex--){
                tableCellElement.removeChild(elementIndex);
            }

            Element firstTextElement = (Element) tableCellElement.getChild(0);
            firstTextElement.removeChildren();
            firstTextElement.appendChild(fullScript);
            scriptNodes.append(firstTextElement);
        }
    }
```

Which will allow using the code `--!jooscript:` in a table cell. Mind that you write your code split over multiple lines in the table cell for directives such as

```
@table:table-row
[#list items as item]
@/table:table-row
[/#list]
```

because further on in the code the actual script is read line-by-line and that fails if you have the script in one long line. Only the first line should have the `--!jooscript:` prefix though.

Answer (score 0):

[**Inserting a script**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Insert_Script) is only supported for LO text or html files. <strike>But you could use a workaround by **inserting a Writer OLE object, for example, into a Calc sheet** (menu "`Insert`" -> "`Object`" -> "`OLE Object`" -> "`LibreOffice 4.2 Text`"). Inside the OLE object, "`Insert`" -> "`Script`" works the same way as in a "native" `.odt` file. The script will appear in the `content.xml` of the `.ods` file as well.</strike>

EDIT: Sorry, doesn't work as i hoped - the script code in fact will be placed in a different `content.xml` (the OLE object has its own `context.xml` in a subdir), but not in the ods' `content.xml`.

Comment: Unfortunately (because I was really excited about this answer), it didn't... What shows up in the content.xml is an embed object, which refers to a folder 'Object1' in the ods-file in which there is a seperate content.xml for the text document. That separate document shows the <text:script> tag, but the main content.xml does not...

Comment: Uh oh - you're right, i just did a quick `grep -R` for my example script's content and didn't notice that i got a hit in the `Object 1` subdirectory... i'm sorry about this!

Comment: No problem, fair try. If no resident stackoverflow genius comes up with something we're missing, I'll fall back to taking a look at the jodreports code and see if I can make it work for other tags.